# Azure Notification Hub not working in WUP app made on Unity3D

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use Azure Notification Hub to handle my MPNS WUP app notifications on a Unity3D generated project.

I used the following article to setup it in Visual Studio 2015 on the generated project: [Getting started with Notification Hubs for Windows Universal Platform Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub)

The app compiles and once it runs the following async code...

```
var result = await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(channel.Uri);
```

...the console prints the following log:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed.dll
WinRT information: ResourceMap Not Found.

Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.AggregateException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
OnWebCamTextureToMatHelperDisposed

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts/generated/Metro/runtime/UnityEngineDebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 45)


Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Unhandled 'Platform.COMException' exception caught! - 'The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.Http.Resources' threw an exception.', Sender: '<null>'. Missing try/catch blocks.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\PlatformDependent/MetroPlayer/MetroDebug.cpp Line: 41)
```

My current setup is:

- Unity3D 5.4.3p4
- Visual Studio 2015
- WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed 0.1.7.9 (I also tried with 0.1.7.8 that is used in the getting started article)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tested also this on a native WUP project using the same how-to article and had the same problem.

In the end we discovered it was not related to Unity or the project configuration as we thought, but to the Azure Account.

The **Pricing Tier** on the the **Microsoft Azure Notification Hub** was defined as **Free** (limit to 500 Active Devices), after changing it to **Basic** (limit to 200K Active Devices) the exception is gone.

This was a really bad experience and took some days for our team to find out the reason as the exception has no real link to the actual issue nor the Microsoft Azure Dashboard has any notification related to the limit on the push registrations.

Comment: Same problem here but this 'solution' does not worked for me.